# Calculating the value of this asset

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, exponential-function, economics

calculate the cash value of a financed asset that is paid in the following way: an initial payment of 500,000, in month 2 a payment equal to half its value, in month 7 a payment equal to a third of its value and in month 10 200,000, the interest rate is 3% and focal date in month 4.

Using the value equation I get:

$$P(1+0.03)^4 = 500000(1+0.03)^4 +\frac{P}{2}(1+0.03)^2+\frac{\frac{P}{3}}{(1+0.03)^3} + \frac{200000}{(1+0.03)^6}$$

solving for P I get:

$$P = 3,175,005$$

Did I set up the value equation correctly?
Is that The correct value of the asset?

Note:

Focal date:A specific time chosen to compare the time value of one or more dated sums of money.

Value equation is:
$$Income_{focaldate} = Expenses_{focaldate}$$

the formula for the future value of money (compound) where F is future, P is present, i is the interest rate and T is the period :

$$F = P(1+i)^T$$

and the Present value

$$P = \frac{F}{(1+i)^T}$$

Comment: Please first clarify the following points: [1] Is the interest rate $3\%$ p.a. or $3\%$ p.m ? [2] payment "in month $2$"presumably means payment after two months [3] whether you are required to compute the valuation *at the focal period*

Comment: what do you mean p.a and p.m? I assume is payment per mont then yes

Comment: yea it means after two months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set up the equation for $P$ (*valuation at start of period*) properly, but I get a different answer for $P$ using your equation, $\approx 2.5$ million, so please recheck your computation.

The other point is that  if the cash value is to be computed for the *focal date*, the answer will be the  value at the focal date,ie $P(1.03)^4$,  not $P$